# Python strings to request, why is it replacing the double quotes with \'var\'?

Tags: python, request

I'm working with [Valhalla](https://valhalla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/matrix/api-reference/#costing-parameters) to retrieve trips durations. In the documentation the format to send the request is as follows:

```
   {"sources":[{"lat":40.744014,"lon":-73.990508}],"targets":[{"lat":40.744014,"lon":-73.990508},{"lat":40.739735,"lon":-73.979713},{"lat":40.752522,"lon":-73.985015},{"lat":40.750117,"lon":-73.983704},{"lat":40.750552,"lon":-73.993519}],"costing":"pedestrian"}&id=ManyToMany_NYC_work_dinner
```

I'm creating the source and the targets independently, this is the code for the source:

```
'{"sources":[{"lat": 19.690742994833027, "lon": -99.1680363639107]'
```

The targets come from a Pandas' series:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  
  .tg td {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg th {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg .tg-0pky {
    border-color: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-0lax {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top
  }
</style>
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 433px">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 91px">
    <col style="width: 342px">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0pky">Reference</th>
      <th class="tg-0pky">order_point</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">[19.690742994833027,-99.1680363639107]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">[19.67109, -99.16845]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">3</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">[19.684034594944944, -99.15103970155211]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">4</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">[19.686485, -99.23003]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">5</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">[19.718996, -99.13548]</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And are turned into a list of dicts:

```
trgt_dicts = [{"lat": i[0], "lon": i[1]} for i in targets]
```

Which returns:

```
[{'lat': 19.690742994833027, 'lon': -99.1680363639107}, {'lat': 19.67109, 'lon': -99.16845}, {'lat': 19.684034594944944, 'lon': -99.15103970155211},  {'lat': 19.686485, 'lon': -99.23003}, {'lat': 19.718996, 'lon': -99.13548}]
```

So, when I put everything together:

```
query = '{"sources":[{"lat": 'f'{source[0]}'', "lon": 'f'{source[1]}''], "targets": 'f'{trgt_dicts}'', "costing":"auto"}'
```

What I get is this:

```
'{"sources":[{"lat": 19.690742994833027, "lon": -99.1680363639107], "targets": [{\'lat\': 19.690742994833027, \'lon\': -99.1680363639107}, {\'lat\': 19.67109, \'lon\': -99.16845}, {\'lat\': 19.684034594944944, \'lon\': -99.15103970155211}, {\'lat\': 19.686485, \'lon\': -99.23003}, {\'lat\': 19.718996, \'lon\': -99.13548}], "costing":"auto"}'
```

Which retrieves and error, and I think the reason is the **\'lon\':** I'm getting instead of **"lon":**

I have tried with json.dumps in an attempt to get the right format as suggested in other questions. I also created variables for the source and the targets and put them together after playing around with the f-string:

```
qsource = '{"sources":[{"lat": 'f'{source[0]}'', "lon": 'f'{source[1]}''], "targets":'
qtrgt = ','.join(map(str, [trgt_dicts]))
query = qsource + qtrgt + ',"costing":"auto"}'
```

But at the end, no matter what, I end up with this **\'lon\':**

Comment: The block of HTML in the middle of your question isn't particularly easy to read. Please remove it and consider replacing it with a simple table (or just the output of printing the pandas series).

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you mean for `query` to be a dictionary, but you're creating a string (by appending a bunch of substrings). Take a closer look at your syntax:

```
query = '{"sources":[{"lat": 'f'{source[0]}'', "lon": 'f'{source[1]}''], "targets": 'f'{trgt_dicts}'', "costing":"auto"}'
```

If we split up the substrings to make it more clear, this is what you've written:

```
query = (
    '{"sources":[{"lat": '
    + f"{source[0]}"
    + ', "lon": '
    + f"{source[1]}"
    + '], "targets": '
    + f"{trgt_dicts}"
    + ', "costing":"auto"}'
)
```

And honestly, that's just weird. I think what you want is something
like:

```
query = {
    "sources": [
        {
            "lat": source[0],
            "lon": source[1],
        },
    ],
    "targets": trgt_dicts,
}
```

That gives you a Python dictionary. If you want to JSON-encode it, you
can use `json.dumps`. Assuming that you have:

```
>>> source
[40.744014, -73.990508]
>>> trgt_dicts
[
    {"lat": 40.744014, "lon": -73.990508},
    {"lat": 40.739735, "lon": -73.979713},
    {"lat": 40.752522, "lon": -73.985015},
    {"lat": 40.750117, "lon": -73.983704},
    {"lat": 40.750552, "lon": -73.993519},
]
```

This gives you:

```
>>> query = {
...     "sources": [
...         {
...             "lat": source[0],
...             "lon": source[1],
...         },
...     ],
...     "targets": trgt_dicts,
... }
>>> print(json.dumps(query, indent=2))
{
  "sources": [
    {
      "lat": 40.744014,
      "lon": -73.990508
    }
  ],
  "targets": [
    {
      "lat": 40.744014,
      "lon": -73.990508
    },
    {
      "lat": 40.739735,
      "lon": -73.979713
    },
    {
      "lat": 40.752522,
      "lon": -73.985015
    },
    {
      "lat": 40.750117,
      "lon": -73.983704
    },
    {
      "lat": 40.750552,
      "lon": -73.993519
    }
  ]
}
```